# Turn and Talk Meaning

Tags: meaning, idioms, idiom-meaning

What is the idiomatic meaning of **turn and talk**? For example:

> I turn and talk like a man leaving charges before a journey.

Comment: There isn’t one. Please edit your question to include the _context_ where you have heard/seen this, as well as what _research_ you have done before asking here – what you’ve looked up in which dictionaries, etc.

Comment: I think you should parse it as "I turn (around)." and "I talk like a man..." But as has been pointed out, this is poetry.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't an "idiom"; it's poetry, in "Song of Myself, 43" by Walt Whitman - 1819-1892. Words of poems don't have to have a literal, everyday meaning. The preceding lines and words introduce various ideas to do with rotation, so 'turn' is appropriate.

> Looking forth on pavement and land, or outside of pavement and land,
>
> Belonging to the winders of the circuit of circuits.
>
> One of that centripetal and centrifugal gang *I turn and talk like a
> man leaving charges before a journey.*

[Song of Myself, 43](https://poets.org/poem/song-myself-43)